# Find n words inside a Mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to create a query that finds a collection of documents that match a criteria, a simple search system. The problem is that the assets inside the collection are like this:

```
{ 
 fristName: "foo",
 lastName: "bar",
 description: "mega foo",
},
{ 
 fristName: "Lorem",
 lastName: "Ipsum",
 description: "mega Lorem bla bla",
},
```

If the user wants all the assets that contains the word *bar* i should show the asset 1 of the example, and that is not a problem, but what if he inputs *foo mega*?, in that case i need also to show the asset 1 because *foo* and *mega* are present in asset 1 (both of them), if he searchs only *mega*, the output is asset 1 and 2, and if he search mega ipsum, the result is asset 2. I have no idea how to write this query in mongoDb.

Comment: Did you try to use [a text index and text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)?

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb 2.6+ has built in support for text searches using the `$text` operator. Here's how to use it.

1. Build an text index on the desired searchable fields. Note: For MongoDB 2.6 you can only have 1 text index on a collection.

   Create text index on one field

   ```
   db.test.ensureIndex({ 
       "field1" : "text"
    }, { name : "Field1TextIndex"});
   ```

   Create text index on two fields

   ```
   db.test.ensureIndex({ 
       "field1" : "text",
       "field2" : "text"
    }, { name : "Field12TextIndex"});
   ```

   Create text index for any string field

   ```
   db.test.ensureIndex({ 
       "$**" : "text" 
   }, { name : "AllTextIndex"});
   ```
2. Query the collection using the $text operator.

   Here's the format for `$text`

   ```
   { $text: { $search: <string of keywords>, $language: <string> } }
   ```

### Example code

#### Setup

```
use test;
var createPerson = function(f,l,d){
    return { firstName : f, lastName: l, description : d};
};
db.test.remove({});
db.test.insert(createPerson("Ben", "Dover", "Real Estate Agent"));
db.test.insert(createPerson("James", "Bond", "secret agent, ben's friend"));
```

#### Creating an text index on all string fields in a document.

```
db.test.ensureIndex({ "$**" : "text" }, { name : "AllTextIndex"});
```

#### Query all fields for keywords

Searching for `ben`

```
db.test.find({  
    $text : {
        $search : "ben"
    }
});
```

#### Output

```
{ "_id" : "...", "firstName" : "James", "lastName" : "Bond", "description" : "secret agent, ben's friend" }
{ "_id" : "...", "firstName" : "Ben", "lastName" : "Dover", "description" : "Real Estate Agent" }
```

The search for "ben" returned both documents since one had `Ben` as the `firstName`, and the other had `ben's` in the `description` field.

Querying for `real friend` produces the same result.

```
db.test.find({  
    $text : {
        $search : "real friend"
    }
});
```

More info here:

- Doc: [Create a text Index on multiple fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/)
- Video: [Demo of MongoDB Text Search and Hashed Shard Keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8wEvWNrIxo)
- Doc: [$text operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to search via keywords. I mean you have to add `keywords` field to each object, like:

```
{ 
 fristName: "foo",
 lastName: "bar",
 description: "mega foo",
 keywords: ["foo", "bar", "mega"]
},
{ 
 fristName: "Lorem",
 lastName: "Ipsum",
 description: "mega Lorem bla bla",
 keywords: ["mega", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "bla"]
},
```

The you have to split request string to keywords, e.g.

```
"foo mega"
```

will be converted into

```
["foo", "mega"]
```

and then you can search objects by `keywords` field.

Comment: I cant modify the structure of the assets, so including the field keywords is not possible

Comment: Without considering the "stemming" options of Full Text Search then I consider this to be a very valid option. Certainly a common sense approach.

Comment: @DomingoSL But the first rule of working with data is to normalize it properly. So it is up to you :).

Comment: @DomingoSL In this domain "I can't modify" is not an acceptible response. Talk to your boss, who clearly needs to be educated. Send him my way.